# How to publish a .Net application to the Windows Store targeting ARM?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2022, desktop-bridge

Reproduce like this:

1. Create a WPF application targeting .Net 6.0  .
2. Add a packaging project, add the WPF application as its
   "Applications", and associate with an app in the Store.
3. Try publishing targeting ARM in both.

This is the exception I get:

> The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win-arm32' is not recognized.

Comment: You might need to ask MSIX package question here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/msix/bd-p/MSIX-Discussions